# Do warnings in Xcode cause the CPU to spike when building?

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to get the temperature down when it builds my app. I don't have experience with Xcode. I'm using version 13.

[image: warnings]

[image: cpu/temp]

[image: macOS version]

Comment: "I don't have experience with Xcode." Well, you do now! This is normal. Your computer has fans so just relax. Certainly as a matter of policy you should reduce / eliminate warnings but the key here is _time_. You want to compile as fast as possible.

Comment: Okay, phew! I will add the warnings to my to-do list. Thank you!!